# I need to return a unique user id in my database function response, how do I go about it

Tags: javascript, node.js

I need to create a unique id for each user added in my database function with `uuid`. This is what I have so far, but I don't get `id` in my JSON response. I am working with firebase.

```
const uuid = require('uuid/v5');

app.post("/", (request, response) => {
    const {age, birthday, firstName, hobby, lastName} = request.body;
    const id = uuid;

    return admin.database().ref('/users').push({age, birthday, firstName, hobby, lastName})
        .then(() => {
            return response.status(200).send({id, age, birthday, firstName, hobby, lastName})
        }).catch(error => {
            console.error(error);
            return response.status(500).send('Oh no! Error: ' + error);
        });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If in the database there is id parameter in the requested parameters should be also id 
 `const {id, age, birthday, firstName, hobby, lastName} = request.body;`

But best idea would be that every new record on DB autoincrement the id value, we haven't to send it from the application

Answer (score 0):

To do this, I created a separate function to handle it

```
const userId = (data) => {
    const string = `${data} ${new Date(Date.now())}`;

    return uuid(string, uuid.DNS);
};
```

This creates a unique id based on the user data given to it and at that particular instant of time.

```
exports.addUserId = functions.database.ref('/users/{pushID}')
    .onCreate((snapshot) => {
        const userData = snapshot.val();

        return snapshot.ref.update({
            id: userId(userData['lastName']),
        });
    });
```